# Alternatives to saying demo session

Tags: american-english, sentence-choice

What are the possible alternatives to conveying demo session. 
Like in tutoring if I want to convey to other student that I won't charge for the first session.
How could one say that in a better way?

Comment: Obviously not what you're looking for, but I see nothing wrong with "I won't charge for the first lesson" (and thereafter referring to it as the "first lesson").

Answer (score 2):

"Trial lesson" would seem to be possible. "Demo session" makes me think of music tracks, recorded at home, to demonstrate a band to a music publisher.

"Free trial" if you want to make it clear that there is no charge for the trial.

Comment: Yeah. Free trial session sounds good